# BigQuery: How to restrict service account access to a range of ip addresses?

Tags: google-cloud-platform

I have an application which has to upload content to google BigQuery service.

A service account is created, everything is working fine with it, but how can I restrict the usage of the account credentials to a range of public ip addresses ?

On aws it is trivial to restrict access on an IAM profile, but I can not find the way to do it on google's IAM administration panel and on google's service account panel.

More generally, is there a way to restrict access ( not rights, access ) to google platform services?

Answer (score 1):

This is a requested feature, but currently it's not possible to set an IP restriction on an IAM policy.

The closest alternative would be to set up a simple service proxy, for example on a [Google Compute Engine instance](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/instances/), which simply forwards the API request along to BigQuery, but has a [firewall policy](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/networking) in place to reject connections outside of the desired IP range.

Comment: The proxy solution does not solve the credentials problem. The issue here is to avoid having valid credentials in the nature. Or you suggest that the proxy should provide also the auth layer for big query requests?

Comment: The proxy should just forward the API request (which includes the 'Authorization' header) along from the client. You'd essentially be calling your own endpoint in lieu of 'https://www.googleapis.com/bigquery/v2/'. It's a roundabout solution but I don't believe there are any alternatives presently.